# Ideas on how to maintain a rhythm on a translated line from a poem

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm trying to translate two lines from a poem while maintaining a rhythm. The one I see most appropriate is:

> Let fate do the work,
>   and live your life
>   carefree.
>
> (Because) in the blink of
>   an eye...
>
> God may flip things
>   upside down.

How can we make  *upside* *down* rhyme with *an* *eye* or with *carefree*?

The original lines literally translate as:

> Let fate do the work (or let fates run in their predestined course) and
>   sleep sound (or go to sleep unconcerned)
>
> In the blink of an eye...
>   God changes things (or changes situations from state to state).

Comment: This site for language learners is not really suited to this kind of question, Rose. It would be better asked on a forum where authors come to discuss their works in progress.

Comment: @Tromano, I tried to delete the question, but it's not woking. Could you please delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Use an AABA rhyme structure, and shift the meaning slightly:

> Let fate be, and live carefree.
>   In the blink of an eye, God makes us see.

Any good?

Comment: It's beautiful. I like it :)